# Cannot use attribute forms in page template?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I have to show a popup by clicking a link that is located in the page template. For this I created a popup within the pageTemplate then inserted a dialogBox and within the dialog box I dragged and dropped my VO from the DataControl panel and inserted it as an ADF form. The problem is that when I run and click the link (that contains the "ShowPopupBehavior") I am getting this error:

```
//C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper/jdev/system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1/MyNew/ViewControllerWebApp.war/WEB-INF/templates/myTemplates.jsf @58,118 value="#{bindings.TypeName.inputValue}": Target Unreachable, 'TypeName' returned null
ADF_FACES-60097:For more information, please see the server's error log for an entry beginning with: ADF_FACES-60096:Server Exception during PPR, #2
```

This happens for every View that I can insert here. Is this comming because I am not allowed to insert ADF forms within the page template?
If so please give me a hint to achieve what I explained in the first sentence.

Comment: Can you check your `pageDef` and search for `TypeName`? The problem is that is doesn't exist there. :)

Comment: Yes the pageDef is fine, and TypeName is just the first attribute of the list. However I figured out the problem and I am posting the solution below. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out the solution to this problem. Each page has its own bindings, so a page that uses the templates (or if want to use bindings from other pages) has to declare that page in the Executables section of the page Bindings. The new executable should have the ID of the page (of the template in this case) and the path of the page. Then the bindings of the template can be accessed as explained here:

```
public String cb1_action() {
BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
DCBindingContainer bindings = 
            (DCBindingContainer)bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
//access the page template Pagedef file reference in the 
//Executable section of the consumer page's Pagedef file
DCBindingContainer templateBinding = 
                (DCBindingContainer)bindings.get("ptb1");
//get the MethodBinding 
OperationBinding printMethod = 
    (OperationBinding)templateBinding .get("printThis");
//invoke the print method exposed on the template's PageDef file
printMethod.getParamsMap().put("message","Hello World");
printMethod.execute();
return null;
}
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_invoke_adf_bindings

ps: Pay attention not to bind the value of the template in your page ex: value="#{bindings.ptb1}"  - it is a bit strange but in this case you will not get the page bindings and will get only the template ones.

Answer (score 0):

The value property containing #{bindings.ptb1} should be removed from the pageTemplate tag but the ptb1 reference has to be in the pages PageDef file.